# What does the warn message "failed to create Hotspot JVM interface, using NilJvm instead" mean?

Tags: scala, finagle, twitter-util

When migrating from Jre11 to Jre17 our backend applications started to log "failed to create Hotspot JVM interface, using NilJvm instead" when starting up.

We use scala with finagle and twitter server and the only difference was the Jre version. We use Zulu Jdk. This `https://cdn.azul.com/zulu/bin/zulu17.44.53-ca-jre17.0.8.1-linux_x64.tar.gz` to be exact. We did use `https://cdn.azul.com/zulu/bin/zulu11.45.27-ca-jre11.0.10-linux_x64.tar.gz` before.

Naturally I would assume it has to do with using Zulu instead of Oracle, but why didn't this show in zulu11 then?

I can't say that I've seen any obvious downside due to this but I did found it hard to interpret what it means from twitter util source code and would like to build an understanding on what the effects of this could be.

Does anyone got experience with this?

Comment: I believe Java 17 (all versions) dropped support for using reflection to acquire references to some of the internal classes of the JVM.  I would expect that most of the loss is in instrumenting things like GC, though it's also possible that some low-level operations in finagle will be using less-optimized versions.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it has. I will dig into the flags to pass to re-enable this reflection to be on the safe side. Although I hope that it doesn't mean finagle works in a less optimized way, given that it is just a warning.